# How do I do a Htaccess 301 redirect with dynamic files

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried many many methods of this but none seem to work.

I upgraded my site to PHP from ASP and as a result now I have 300+ `404`'s which i should of seen coming, but oh well.

Problem is I need to redirect these files and they are all dynamic:

old files are like: `http://www.domain.co.uk/resoucecentreDetails.asp?title=foobar&ID=37`

There are literally 100s of these so is there a quick way I can redirect them to a single page i.e. `http://www.domain.co.uk/resoucecentreSelect.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rewrite Rules in .htaccess.

Write following Rule in your htaccess.. It will redirect all your dynamic URLs to one page..

```
RewriteRule ^resoucecentreDetails.asp?title=(.*)&ID=(.*)$ /resoucecentreSelect.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule will do the job:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect rule
RewriteRule ^resoucecentreDetails.asp$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/resoucecentreSelect.php [NC,QSA,R=301,L]
```

It will redirect all requests from `/resoucecentreDetails.asp` to `/resoucecentreSelect.php` **preserving** the query string, e.g.:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/resoucecentreDetails.asp?title=foobar&ID=37
```

will become

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/resoucecentreSelect.php?title=foobar&ID=37
```